# Delete pending task in SimGrid

Tags: simgrid

I have process `worker` which launches `executor`. `Executor` is a process which creates a 10-sec task and executes it. But after 2 sec worker kills `executor` process. SimGrid gives me a log  after killing `executor`:

```
[  2.000000] (0:maestro@) dp_objs: 1 pending task?
```

How should I properly destroy tasks and `task_data` when another process kill currently working process?

```
int worker(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    msg_process_t x = MSG_process_create("", executor, NULL, MSG_host_self());
    MSG_process_sleep(2);
    MSG_process_kill(x);
}

int executor(){
    MSG_process_on_exit(my_onexit, NULL);
    task = MSG_task_create("", 1e10, 10, NULL);
    MSG_task_execute(task);
    return 0;
}
int my_onexit() {
     MSG_task_cancel(task);
     XBT_INFO("Exiting now (done sleeping or got killed).");
     return 0;
}
```

**UPD**:
I declared a global variable `msg_task_t task`.

Now when I run code I have:

```
[  2.000000] (0:maestro@) Oops ! Deadlock or code not perfectly clean.
[  2.000000] (0:maestro@) 1 processes are still running, waiting for something.
[  2.000000] (0:maestro@) Legend of the following listing: "Process <pid> (<name>@<host>): <status>"
[  2.000000] (0:maestro@) Process 2 (@Worker2)
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I expected that simgrid would show `xbt_info` message, but it didn't and interrupted with `SIGABRT` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `MSG_task_cancel()` the task that you want to "kill". You could do that in a function that is registered in the `MSG_process_on_exit()` callback.

Comment: How can I reach to `task` in `onexit` function?

Comment: You have to store it in a global (or in MSG_process_set_data()) before you start executing it. That's much easier than digging in the SimGrid internals to retrieve it afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking again about it, the message that you see is not an error message but merely a warning. You can ignore it safely. I am pretty sure that executed tasks are automatically canceled when the processor is killed.

So you don't have anything to do anything to get it working, I'd say. Just ignore that message.

Comment: Does cancelling a task destroy it?